# Call inline funcion returning string in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to call a function that return a string for construct an url. Something like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
    <a ng-href="{{ getHost(campaign.country)}}/campaign/{{campaign._id}}">View</a>
</div>
```

My controller code:

```
$rootScope.getHost = function(code){
    ApiService.getHost(code).then(function(response) {
       return response.data.url;
    });
 }
```

My Provider:

```
var getHost = function(code){

   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var $this = this;
   $http.get(host + "/api/findHosts?code="+code).then(function (response) {
       deferred.resolve(response);
   }, function (response) {
       deferred.reject(response);
   });

   return deferred.promise
}
```

My function getHost `{{ getHost(campaign.country)}}` return the host depends on the country of the campaign. But this it's not working. What it's the way for doing something like that? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for your controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use `ng-click` in this case, build the url in the function you call with it, then call the url with `window.location.href=url` in the function.

Comment: I change that, but it's still not working. My browser is crashing when I load the page.

Comment: hmm, ahh i forgot about the function, the reason it is crashing is that you are calling the digest loop infinity.

Comment: It's not working, but it's weird: `<a ng-init="host = getHost(campaign.country)" ng-show=" host!='' " ng-href="http://{{host}}/campaign/{{campaign._id}}">View</a>` There are countries without host, and the function returns empty. And the ng-show directive it's working well. But not the ng-href

Comment: you might be better off using `ng-click` that calls a function, that creates the  URL string then call the url with `window.location.href=url;`

Comment: No problem! Can you mark this answer as the solution. Thanks!